# Gulp Autoprefixer not prefixing

Tags: jquery, gulp, autoprefixer

My Autoprefixer is not adding the necessary prefixes to the compiled CSS. I've read various posts including stack posts and tried changing the order and variations of the task including:

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({
browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie6', 'ie7', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4']
})
```

This is my GULP FILE:

```
    var
            gulp         = require('gulp'),
            compass      = require('gulp-compass'),
            autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
            concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
            notify       = require('gulp-notify'),
            livereload   = require('gulp-livereload'),
            plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
            path         = require('path');

        // the title and icon that will be used for the Grunt notifications
        var notifyInfo = {
            title: 'Gulp',
            icon: path.join(__dirname, 'gulp.png')
        };

        //error notification settings for plumber
        var plumberErrorHandler = { errorHandler: notify.onError({
                title: notifyInfo.title,
                icon: notifyInfo.icon,
                message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
            })
        };

        // The default task (called when you run `gulp` from cli)
        gulp.task('default', ['watch']);

        // CSS
        gulp.task('css', function() {

            return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*')
              .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
              .pipe(compass({
                config_file: './src/config.rb',
                css: './css',
                sass: './src/scss'
              }))
              .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))      
              .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

        });

        // JS
        gulp.task('js', function() {
            var scripts = [
                './src/js/no-conflict.js',
                //'./node_modules/owl-carousel-2/owl.carousel.js',
                './src/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
                './src/js/wow.js',
                './src/js/frontend.js'
            ];

            gulp.src(scripts)
                .pipe(concat('script.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
                .pipe(notify({ message: 'Successfully compiled JavaScript' }));

        });

        // Images
        gulp.task('images', function() {
        });

        // Fonts
        gulp.task('fonts', function() {
        });

        // Watch
        gulp.task('watch', function() {

            //livereload();

            //livereload.listen();

            // Watch .scss files
            gulp.watch('./src/scss/**/*.scss', ['css']);

            // Watch .js files
            gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['js']);

            // Reload when template file, css or js file changes
            var watchlist = [
                './css/style.css',
                './js/frontend.js'
            ];

            gulp.watch(watchlist, function(event) {
                gulp.src(event.path)
                    .pipe(plumber())
                    .pipe(livereload())
                    .pipe(notify({
                            title: notifyInfo.title,
                            icon: notifyInfo.icon,
                            message: event.path.replace(__dirname, '').replace(/\\/g, '/') + ' was ' + event.type + ' and reloaded'
                        })
                    );
            });
        });
```

Can some one point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup looks correct. What version of autoprefixer are you running? I think "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0", is the latest. Have you tried commenting out:

```
.pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
              .pipe(compass({
                config_file: './src/config.rb',
                css: './css',
                sass: './src/scss'
              }))
```

And then re-running your task?

Try installing node module cssnano and then give this a go:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('./src/scss/**/*')
    .pipe(sass({style: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 4 version'))
    .pipe(cssnano({
      convertValues: {
        length: false
      },
      discardComments: {
        removeAll: true
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
});
```

Comment: i'm running version 3.10.10 and i tried commenting out the above but it did not work.

Comment: Does 'last 2 versions' make any difference?  Note the "s" in versions.

Comment: I can't an error when I install css-nano and also when i run gulp...  `Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir...`

Comment: i use with gulp-minify-css instead and got the autoprefixer and minification working.

Comment: Use sudo before the npm install to avoid the error.